# Check employee input from shift work

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form I run for my workbook that basically does 3 things:
Let's people sign in into the shift
Checks if the person is signing in for the right shift
And lets me find common errors by logging people who sign in at the wrong shift.
There are 2 shifts "dia"(day - 8 to 18) and "Noite"(Night - 18 to 8) and as you can see the whole is a mess as there is too many if and else's. I tried changing into a select case, but it looks almost the same. 
I would appreciate any pointers that you guys could give me to simplify my code. This would also prevent me to commit any errors (I bet I am forgetting to put stuff here right now) and make it easier to edit in the future.

The code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long
Dim login As String
Dim Ct As String
Dim lpass As Variant
Set ws = Worksheets("Formularios")
Set wb = Worksheets("Time")

If Trim(Me.cbUtilizador.Value) = "" Then
  Me.cbUtilizador.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Por favor Selecionar um Utilizador"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.txtCT.Value) = "" Then
  Me.cbUtilizador.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Por favor Contar Caixa de Trocos"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.cbTurno.Value) = "" Then
  Me.cbTurno.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Por favor Selecionar Turno"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.txtPass.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txtPass.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Por favor inserir Password"
  Exit Sub
End If

Ct = Replace(txtCT, ".", ",")
If Not Ct = "" Then
    If IsNumeric(Ct) = True Then
        Caixa = CDbl(Ct)
    End If
End If


login = Me.cbUtilizador.Value
lpass = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(login, Sheets("Pass").Range("AC2:AD15"), 2, False)

If Me.txtPass.Value = lpass Then
    If Me.cbTurno.Value = "Dia" Then
        If Hour(Now) < 8 Or Hour(Now) > 18 Then
            If MsgBox("Está no horário do turno Noturno. Tem certeza que quer entrar no turno do dia?", vbYesNo, "Turno do Dia") = vbYes Then
                With ws
                    .Unprotect Password:=pass
                    .Range("G2") = Me.cbUtilizador.Value
                    .Range("G3") = Me.cbTurno.Value
                    .Range("G13") = Me.txtCT.Value
                    .Protect Password:=pass
                End With
                With wb
                    .Unprotect Password:=pass
                    .Range("L" & Range("Time!L1048000").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Now & " " & Me.cbUtilizador.Value & " " & Me.cbTurno.Value
                    .Range("I1").Value = countI + 1
                    .Protect Password:=pass
                End With
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            With ws
                .Unprotect Password:=pass
                .Range("G2") = Me.cbUtilizador.Value
                .Range("G3") = Me.cbTurno.Value
                .Range("G13") = Me.txtCT.Value
                .Protect Password:=pass
            End With
            With wb
                .Unprotect Password:=pass
                .Range("I1").Value = countI + 1
                .Protect Password:=pass
            End With
            Audit
        End If
        Calc
        wTurno = Me.cbTurno.Value
        Unload Me
    Else
        If Hour(Now) > 8 And Hour(Now) < 18 Then
            If MsgBox("Está no horário do turno Diário. Tem certeza que quer entrar no turno do Noite?", vbYesNo, "Turno da Noite") = vbYes Then
                With ws
                    .Unprotect Password:=pass
                    .Range("G2") = Me.cbUtilizador.Value
                    .Range("G3") = Me.cbTurno.Value
                    .Range("G13") = Me.txtCT.Value
                    .Protect Password:=pass
                End With
                With wb
                    .Unprotect Password:=pass
                    .Range("L" & Range("Time!L1048000").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Now & " " & Me.cbUtilizador.Value & " " & Me.cbTurno.Value
                    .Range("I1").Value = countI + 1
                    .Protect Password:=pass
                End With
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            With ws
                .Unprotect Password:=pass
                .Range("G2") = Me.cbUtilizador.Value
                .Range("G3") = Me.cbTurno.Value
                .Range("G13") = Me.txtCT.Value
                .Protect Password:=pass
            End With
            With wb
                .Unprotect Password:=pass
                .Range("I1").Value = countI + 1
                .Protect Password:=pass
            End With
            Audit
        End If
        wTurno = Me.cbTurno.Value
        Calc
        CloseC
        Calc
        Unload Me
    End If
Else
    MsgBox ("There is a problem - check your password, capslock, etc.")
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "I tried changing into a select case, but it looks almost the same." Did you take a look at the maintainability aspect as well? All of a sudden there's a good difference between if/else and a select case.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand Portuguese, for the top checking parts, they should have been done as user types. Initialise should have most Controls disabled until login successful. More Interactive for User, and so, when all criteria reached, then enable the **cmdAdd**. By the way do you have `Option Explicit` enabled? The rest seems to be able to factorize down.

Comment: @PatricK thank you for that. I had completely forgot you could set as a user types. Made it much easier to setup. I have "option Expicit" as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One area for consideration is removing duplication.

You repeat the following code multiple times.

```
        With ws
            .Unprotect Password:=pass
            .Range("G2") = Me.cbUtilizador.Value
            .Range("G3") = Me.cbTurno.Value
            .Range("G13") = Me.txtCT.Value
            .Protect Password:=pass  ' is this supposed to be 'lpass' ?
        End With
```

Consider, instead having a subroutine such as (untested of course):

```
Private Sub UpdateWS(selectedWS as Worksheet, valUtil as String, valTurn as String, valCT as String, valPass as Variant)
With selectedWS
            .Unprotect Password:=valPass
            .Range("G2") = valUtil
            .Range("G3") = valTurn
            .Range("G13") = valCT
            .Protect Password:=valPass  
        End With
End sub
```

And then call it in your main routine with

```
UpdateWS ws, Me.cbUtilizador.Value, Me.cbTurno.Value, Me.txtCT.Value, lpass
```

This means that if you make a minor change (e.g. change a cell location or correct `lpass` from `pass`) then you only have to do it once. It also provides future flexibility if you want to tailor any of the input strings from the branches.

You can also do the same with

```
       With wb
            .Unprotect Password:=pass
            .Range("L" & Range("Time!L1048000").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Now & " " & Me.cbUtilizador.Value & " " & Me.cbTurno.Value
            .Range("I1").Value = countI + 1
            .Protect Password:=pass
        End With
```

Where the second .line could be behind an `iif(parameter = true, do, do not do)` or `if dotrue then do` because that line doesn't appear in every one. An example of the function signature is:

```
Private Sub UpdateWB(selectedWB as WorkBook, valUtil as String, valTurn as String, valCT as String, valPass as Variant, doCondStatement as Boolean)
```

The additional advantage of modularising in this manner is to identify further duplication. Having typed the above, I can now see that UpdateWS and UpdateWB are largely similar and your original code will always call both within each conditional statement. You could combine the two into a single private subroutine, with a signature like:

```
Private Sub UpdateWSandWB(selectedWB as WorkBook, selectedWS as WorkSheet, valUtil as String, valTurn as String, valCT as String, valPass as Variant, doCondStatement as Boolean)
```

Once you have done this (remembering that the primary aim was originally to remove duplication), you will see that `doCondStatement` can be calculated from your `if` statements. You will also be able to identify other patterns in your code that may lead to further simplifying or modularising.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This made the code much clearer.